# Setting up additional Tomcat server on OSX / Unix

Tags: java, macos, apache, tomcat

I'm running into a few problems setting up tomcat to run on port "80" on a mac. I've looked on Stackoverflow and Google but I haven't found an answer that works so I will explain my problem as clearly as I can.

I have 2 versions of tomcat 7 installed on my mac for development which I run at different times.

One Tomcat install (tomcat1) is being used by Netbeans with standard configuration on port "8080" redirect at "8443". This is working fine.

I have another Tomcat install (tomcat2) which has a modified configuration in the server.xml file. Namely I have had to change the port to "80", and the redirectPort to "443".

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="my_jks_file"
           keystorePass="mypassword" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" />
```

So before changing the settings tomcat2 ran fine. However after changing the settings for tomcat2 it will not start and is giving me the error below. How can I fix this? From my search it appears I need to run tomcat as root...or something similar. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
Feb 13, 2013 1:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Feb 13, 2013 1:25:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Feb 13, 2013 1:25:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:80
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 17 more
Feb 13, 2013 1:25:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:80
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 17 more
Feb 13, 2013 1:25:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
Feb 13, 2013 1:25:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:443
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:84)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 17 more
Feb 13, 2013 1:25:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:658)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:443
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:84)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hd1 said, you must be root to bind to ports below 1024. However, you should not run as root - this is a recipe for desaster.

Rather use apache httpd or the webserver of your favor to bind to port 80 and then delegate to tomcat. For this you can use mod_proxy, mod_jk2 or mod_proxy_ajp - look up the documentation for these, there's plenty to find.

The advantage of this setup is that Apache drops the root privileges and you're not exposing a service with superuser permissions to the internet: Think about the damage that can be done when there is a security violation with this setup - there'd be a root process remotecontroled.

If you already ran as root (e.g. `sudo ...`) make sure to change ownership of the temporary files and directories that have been created as root.

Comment: I agree, but you don't even need to use an apache front-end.`jsvc` already supports this

Comment: yes, now that I re-read your answer with the rest (initial statement is misleading: 80 is not busy with this exception). However, I very much prefer the apache setup - it adds flexibility, but that's personal preference and adds another option to the toolbox

Comment: Ok.Just mentioning it in case you were not aware of this.Could be useful some day.You never know

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error:        INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:

Comment: That's not an error, but an information. If you have a high traffic website, you might want this to increase performance. If you have low traffic or don't need to worry about squeezing milliseconds from request processing, you're good. A quick glance to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html suggests that the APR is available for Windows and Linux - not Mac - anyway (but I didn't check thoroughly)

Comment: hmmm....ok thanks for the help your solution got rid of my errors but tomcat won't start up and I can't see any errors.

Comment: ...but that sounds unrelated to the problem discussed in the original question, right? It might be easier to isolate the problem and post a follow up question than to go into a chat-like comment stream here

Comment: One can build [APR](https://apr.apache.org/) on the mac pretty straightforwardly by [following the instructions](https://apr.apache.org/compiling_unix.html), but like @OlafKock said:  If you have a high traffic website, you might want this to increase performance. If you have low traffic or don't need to worry about squeezing milliseconds from request processing, you're good.

Answer (score 2):

Some process is already using port `80`.
Use `netstat` to find it or use an available port.

Another alternative is that although in `Windows` you can bind to `80` as non-root may be it is not possible for Mac. In linux it is not.
If in Mac you can not bind as non-root to port `80` and if it is a requirement for you to run as non-root, you can still bind to `80` (and any other port < 1024)  but by using [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html) as "wrapper". It will allow you to bind to ports <1024 as non-root.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start as root to bind to ports less than 1024 on Unix-like systems. So, use `sudo bin/catalina.sh start` and it should work. Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, will work - but this should never be done, see my answer for reasons